# Kivy accordion change highlighted color

Tags: python, kivy

I'm still new to kivy but loving it. In a kivy accordion by default the highlighted accordion item is blue. I would like to change that to red. I've gone through the documentation at http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.accordion.html and I still can't seem to find it.  I'd rather do it inside the python script than having to create a .kv file. Is it possible?

```
accord = Accordion(anim_duration=1.5, orientation='vertical')
item = AccordionItem(title="Hello World, touch here to turn this red")
item.add_widget(Label(text="Useless Label, font_size='20sp', text_size=(1100, None), halign="center"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the images used to display the `AccordionItem` by setting these four properties:

`background_normal`
`background_disabled_normal`
`background_selected`
`background_disabled_selected`

i.e. `item = AccordionItem(title="Hello World", background_selected="path/to/image/file.png")`